# Tkinter: how to use a separate Window to ask the user for input via buttons and return that value to the original function

Tags: python, tkinter

I currently have to write a chess game in Python using nothing but Tkinter in order to get my highschool diploma and I'm currently struggeling with the following:
When a pawn reaches the backline, it can be promoted. I want to create a Pop-up window with Buttons the user can click in order to select what kind of piece his pawn should be promoted to. It currently looks like this:

```
def getPromotePawnPiece() -> str:
    optionsWindow = Toplevel()
    selected_piece = "None"
    pawnField = Button(optionsWindow, text="Pawn", anchor=W, command=lambda: 
                               returnPieceSelected("Pawn", optionsWindow, selected_piece))
    rookField = Button(optionsWindow, text="Rook", anchor=W, command=lambda: 
                               returnPieceSelected("Rook", optionsWindow, selected_piece))
    bishopField = Button(optionsWindow, text="Bishop", anchor=W, command=lambda: 
                               returnPieceSelected("Bishop", optionsWindow, selected_piece))
    knightField = Button(optionsWindow, text="Knight", anchor=W, command=lambda: 
                               returnPieceSelected("Knight", optionsWindow, selected_piece))
    queenField = Button(optionsWindow, text="Queen", anchor=W, command=lambda: 
                               returnPieceSelected("Queen", optionsWindow, selected_piece))

pawnField.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=NSEW)
rookField.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=NSEW)
bishopField.grid(row=1, column=3, sticky=NSEW)
knightField.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky=NSEW)
queenField.grid(row=1, column=4, sticky=NSEW)

def returnPieceSelected(selected_piece_via_button: str, window: Toplevel, selected_piece_var: 
str):
     window.destroy()
     selected_piece_var = selected_piece_via_button
```

The Window gets created successfully but I have no way to get the information of which button has been clicked to the original root Window
In case it helps: the "main" Window is globally created, getPromotePiece() is called after a Pawn has reached the last row

Comment: Have you tried assigning to `selected_piece` instead of `selected_piece_var` in `returnPieceSelected()`, and then using `return selected_piece` at the end of `getPromotedPawnPiece()`?

Comment: @SylvesterKruin That was my first thought, but since selected_piece is defined in the getPromotedPawnPiece() method I have no access to it in the returnPieceSelected() method and Python doesn't (as far as I'm aware) support pass-by-reference

Comment: Does it give an error message when you try to do so? If so, have you tried using `global selected_piece` at the beginning of both `getPromotedPawnPiece` and `returnPieceSelected`?

Comment: @SylvesterKruin It does not give an error message. I already thought about making a global variable out of it so that I can use it in the "main" Window and in the Pop-Up but I've been told to avoid using globals as much as possible. The main issue I face is returning the information from returnPieceSelected to the caller of getPromotePawnPiece since I don't know how I store the returned value from a method if its called with the command=...... expression

Comment: I don't understand. What is wrong with what I first suggested, if it doesn't give any error messages?

Comment: @Kerialstraz `global` variables are not that bad, yes they can cause issues and stuff but literally any name that is outside of a function or a class is a global name, so if you simply in your script defined sth like `var = 10`, it would be considered global since you could access it anywhere in the script, it is a bit more than that, but basically for small programs you should be fine using global variables with `global`, just make sure you don't have any other variable representing another value anywhere with the same name, also if you really want to avoid `global` you have to use `class`es

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First use `StringVar` for `selected_piece`, so that it can be set inside `returnPieceSelected()`.

Then use `optionsWindow.wait_window()` inside `getPromotePawnPiece()` to wait for selection:

```py
def returnPieceSelected(selected_piece_via_button: str, window: Toplevel, selected_piece_var: StringVar):
    window.destroy()
    # save selection
    selected_piece_var.set(selected_piece_via_button)

def getPromotePawnPiece() -> str:

    optionsWindow = Toplevel()
    selected_piece = StringVar(value="None") # use StringVar instead of normal string
    pawnField = Button(optionsWindow, text="Pawn", anchor=W, command=lambda:
                               returnPieceSelected("Pawn", optionsWindow, selected_piece))
    rookField = Button(optionsWindow, text="Rook", anchor=W, command=lambda:
                               returnPieceSelected("Rook", optionsWindow, selected_piece))
    bishopField = Button(optionsWindow, text="Bishop", anchor=W, command=lambda:
                               returnPieceSelected("Bishop", optionsWindow, selected_piece))
    knightField = Button(optionsWindow, text="Knight", anchor=W, command=lambda:
                               returnPieceSelected("Knight", optionsWindow, selected_piece))
    queenField = Button(optionsWindow, text="Queen", anchor=W, command=lambda:
                               returnPieceSelected("Queen", optionsWindow, selected_piece))

    pawnField.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=NSEW)
    rookField.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=NSEW)
    bishopField.grid(row=1, column=3, sticky=NSEW)
    knightField.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky=NSEW)
    queenField.grid(row=1, column=4, sticky=NSEW)

    # wait for user selection
    optionsWindow.wait_window()

    # return user selection
    return selected_piece.get()
```